# Open excel file and sort contents using a Batch file commands

Tags: file, sorting, batch-file, using

I am looking for a code that can be written that would open excel and sort a field within the opened workbook.

A thought would be to:

```
set the workbook to run a vba sorting script on open 
start Excel.exe filename.xls
```

Would this be a viable option? If so, how would I initiate the vba script on open?

Comment: Your requirement can be interpreted multiple ways, so it is confusing. Is the string in the file name? or the file content? Also, you haven't asked a question, let alone a programming question. You have simply stated what your requirement is. Edit your question to be more clear, and show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show only the files which contains "`PRE100`" in the file name:

```
@echo off

For %%f in (SOURCE_PATH\*PRE100*.*) do Echo %%f
```

Move only the files which contains "`PRE100`" in the file name, to another dir:

```
@echo off

For %%f in (SOURCE_PATH\*PRE100*.*) do Move %%f DESTINY_PATH
```

Change `SOURCE_PATH` and `DESTINY_PATH` to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

When I read your question right, "PRE100" is not in the filename, but in the file contents.

```
for /f %%i in ('dir /b *.*') do find /i  "PRE100" "%%i">nul && move "%%i" newFolder
```

for all files do: if it contains "PRE100" then move it.

`find /i` makes the search case insensitive (finds PRE100, Pre100, pre100)

`&&` acts as "if previous command was successful, then"

The doublequotes around `%%i` are needed to work with filenames, that contains spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it!!!

Let me know if there are any drawbacks to doing it this way:

```
 @ECHO OFF

 robocopy "PRIMARY_DIR"  "DEST_DIR" 

 *PRE100*.* /XN

 %SystemRoot%\explorer.exe "DEST_DIR"

 cmd /k Path to the O.bat
```